# Drawing multiple primitives in D3D11 with and without Index Buffers

Tags: directx, directx-11

For example, if I want to draw a triangle and a square on the same scene, what is the proper technique to do so? I know that using index buffers is faster, but I wish to know the technique which does not employ index buffers for educational purposes.

Assume rudimentary knowledge of directx in your answers.

Comment: What's wrong with the normal way, filling your vertices into a vertexbuffer and render them? Therefore you need no indexbuffer. Or did I understand your question incorrectly?

Comment: I want to know both ways of doing it basically.

Comment: There are so many tutorials in the internet for DirecX. You should start there. (e.g. [Tut](http://www.rastertek.com/tutdx11.html))